# gVim with portable python?

Tags: python, vim, portability

I'm running a standalone gvim with support for python 2.7 and I downloaded portable python so I could use it with gvim. Is there any way I could configure gvim to use portable python? I've already tried adding portable python's path in my vimrc file and I can verify it's correct. But `:echo has('python')` still returns 0.

Answer (score 3):

First, check that the Python DLL version matches the `:version` output:

> ```
> Linking: ... /nodefaultlib:python27.lib
> ```

Second, the `python27.dll` must be accessible to Vim, so ensure it can be loaded via the system `PATH` variable, or copy it into an accessible directory; modifying via `:let $PATH = ...` probably won't suffice.

Comment: Ok, apparently my path wasn't pointing to the folder in python portable that had the pyhton27.dll so I fixed that. Now I get a Runtime error when I try `echo has('python')`: An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: That probably means the library is incompatiblem, and you need to use the vanilla Python install. It wouldn't hurt to ask on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php) for help / experiences, though.